# Finding cooccuring values in MYSQL weak relation table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a weak relation table, called `header`, it is basically just three ID's: `id` is an autoincrement primary key, `did` points to the id of table D and `hid` points to the id of table H. D and H are irrelevant here.
I want to find for any value of `hid`, the other values of `hid` that shares `did` with the original `hid`. An example:

```
id | did | hid
===============
1  | 1   | 1
2  | 1   | 2
3  | 1   | 3
4  | 2   | 1
5  | 2   | 4
6  | 2   | 5
7  | 3   | 2
8  | 3   | 6
```

For `hid = 1` I would thus like to find `id = {2,3,5,6}` as those are the rows that have `did` in common with `hid = 1`.

I can do this by creating some arrays in PHP and running through all possible values of `hid` and respective `did`, but this is a quite slow process for large tables. I was wondering if there is a clever kind of `JOIN` or similar statement that could be used to find the cooccuring values of `hid`.

Comment: `id = 4` satisfies the condition, not the ones you've shown.

Comment: It's the other way around. I don't want to find other occurences of `hid = 1`. I want to find the `id` where the `did` is the same as in all `hid = 1` cases, but with `hid != 1`

Comment: I guess a more clear example would be: I have two values of `hid`, 1 and 2. How many times do they share `did`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly:-

```
SELECT a.hid, GROUP_CONCAT(b.id)
FROM header a
INNER JOIN header b
ON a.did = b.did
AND b.hid != 1
WHERE a.hid = 1
GROUP BY a.hid
```

SQL fiddle:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9aa26/1

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question exactly, and gives a lot of inspiration for further studies.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT d.id
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM header
   WHERE header.hid =1
) AS h
JOIN header AS d ON d.did = h.did
WHERE d.hid !=1
```